# Retrieve map inside map Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have data structure as:

```
        val drinks = hashMapOf(
        "cola" to hashMapOf(
            "price" to 36,
            "amount" to 15
        )
    )
```

I use firestore and want to retrieve price.

```
        db.collection("category").document("drinks").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {documentSnapshot->
            documentSnapshot.data?.forEach {
            //it ->  Map.Entry<String!,Any!>
                Log.d(TAG, "for each data: ${it.key} ${it.value}")
            }
            if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "read data: ${documentSnapshot["sultan"]}")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null")
            }
    }
```

I tried to convert it as list of objects, but nothing helps

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way to handle the data with Firebase in kotlin.

```
.addOnSuccessListener { docsSnapshot ->
    for (docSnapshot in docsSnapshot.documents) {
        val hashmap = docSnapshot.data
        hashmap?.put("id", docSnapshot.id)
        Log.e("hashmap", hashmap) // This hashmap holds your document id and rest of data.
        val Data = Gson().toJson(hashmap)
        val docsData = Gson().fromJson<Drinks>(Data, Drinks::class.java)
        Log.e("docsData", docsData) // Now you can access what type of data you need.
    }
}
```

POKO For your data :

```
class Drinks{
    val id : String,
    val amount : Long,
    val price : Long,
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but it doesn't work, can you help me?

Comment: Please post your issue in proper manner to understand what's not working ?

Comment: Log.e("hashmap", hashmap) returns this:  {sprite={amount=60, price=89}, id=drinks, cola={amount=15, price=36}}   but    Log.e("docsData", docsData) returns this : Products(list=[]). My  dataclass is this:      data class Product(var amount:Long = 0, var price: Long = 0L)
data class Products(var list:List<Product> = emptyList())

Comment: @Nurseyit Please pojo you have tried it needs to be something like this